# Программное закрытие нотификации

Tags: android

Есть приемник широковещательных намерений, который в некотором случае посылает нотификацию(Notification) при клике по ней мы открываем окно, точнее вызываем новый Intent. Вопрос как сделать что бы нотификация пропадала из статус бара при клике на ней/открытии нового интента.
P.s как ее просто убрать я знаю, но мне нужно именно тогда как мы кликнули по ней и перешли в новый интент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `Notification` при создании нужно выставить соответствующий флаг, [`FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL). Тогда при клике по нотификации, она автоматически исчезнет.

Примерно так:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
```